# Syntax error while INSERT MySql from Java

Tags: java, mysql, syntax, insert, timestamp

I get an syntax error while trying to INSERT some values to Mysql from Java.

My code looks like this:

```
date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(nextLine[0]);
        java.sql.Timestamp sqlDate = new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime());
        st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO " + tick + "(day, open, high, low, close, volume) VALUES (" + sqlDate + ", " + nextLine[1] + ", " + nextLine[2] + ", " + nextLine[3] + ", " + nextLine[4] + ", " + nextLine[5] + ")");
```

My exception:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '00:00:00.0,
>   128.40, 128.50, 127.30, 128.20, 1415200)' at line 1

Would be glad for any help :)

Comment: Please show your query that is send to the db

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While it would be possible to just fix the immediate syntax error, I would *strongly* recommend against it. You shouldn't be including the values directly in your SQL at all.

Instead, use a parameterized query via `PreparedStatement`, and set your values into the parameters instead. In this case, you'd use [`PreparedStatement.setTimestamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTimestamp%28int,%20java.sql.Timestamp%29) to set the value - after changing the query to be parameterized in the first place, of course.

Benefits of parameterized SQL:

- Prevention of [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)
- Avoidance of error-prone string conversions (as witnessed in this case)
- Separation of code and data, leading to SQL which is simpler to read

Comment: Thank you. I will take a look at PreparedStatemet and see if i get it! Am totaly new to MySql so.. :P

Comment: @ZedIsDead: This is something you should be looking to do whenever you use *any* database from *any* programming language. If some database/language pair doesn't support it, forcing you to build the SQL directly, that should be a warning sign...

Comment: PS: Is "ZedIsDead" a reference to the Quentin Tarantino movie, or the John Boorman movie "Zardoz" that Quentin Tarantino paid homage to?  Or something else entirely?

Answer (score 1):

STRONG SUGGESTION:

1) Create a Java string variable before you call executeUpdate()

2) Make sure your string is syntactically correct (dates quoted, commas between values, etc etc)

ALSO:

"prepare" is your friend ;)

- http://www.jdbc-tutorial.com/jdbc-prepared-statements.htm

I *think* you might already be using them ... but you didn't show that part of the code ... and I certainly didn't see any placemarkers ("?")

But I think 1) making the string first, and 2) inspecting the string (e.g. in your debugger) before your JDBC call will be a huge help... IMHO...

Answer (score 0):

Dates need to be quoted in MySQL so you'll ned to wrap `sqlDate` with single quotes:

```
st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO " + tick + "(day, open, high, low, close, volume) VALUES ('" + sqlDate + "', " + nextLine[1] + ", " + nextLine[2] + ", " + nextLine[3] + ", " + nextLine[4] + ", " + nextLine[5] + ")");
```

I'm assuming the other values are numeric and therefore are safe without quotes.

The biggest issue with this approach is that you are susceptible to [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should switch to using prepared statements instead:

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO my_table(day, open, high, low, close, volume) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
ps.setTimestamp(1, sqlDate);
ps.setBigDecimal(2, nextLine[1]);
...
```